# Using store magic in ipython from a file

Tags: ipython

The documentation for the %store magic states that you can store your variables to a file.

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/config/extensions/storemagic.html

ie: %store foo >a.txt - Store value of foo to new file a.txt
%store foo >>a.txt - Append value of foo to file a.txt

I have been able to successfully write the variables to a file, which is readable in plain text. (although it appears that it leaves out some data, since there are ellipse).

How do i restore these variables? The typical command is %store -r, but %store doesn't show any variables.

Comment: If you want to store variables in a named file, it's probably easier to use the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) directly; the store magic is using that internally anyway. But if you want to archive or share data, you should probably pick another format like JSON or CSV that will be less closely tied to your code.

Comment: Looks like a bug, no issue is open currently https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+store+magic. But the lack of activiy on this question says few people need it. I'll use pickle.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find in the documentation how to "load" from file after using `%store`. I guess the `%store -r var_name` is only meant when you saved on the "default" storage used by `%store`.

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html

But here are 2 ways. I'd love to see a better one.

Saving

[image]

Loading with `%load`

`%load file_to_load`

[image]

Load "manually" (just one way)

[image]

```
x=!cat out_file.txt
x
y=eval(''.join(x)) # Always be careful when using 'eval'
y
```